# Adaptable Year in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Pretty simple question but still a valid one. If had code like this:

```
let Halloween = new Date("October 31");
console.log(Halloween);
```

How would one make the year the year adapt to the current year each time rather than automatically set to 2001?

I know you can get the current year using a system like this but how would I insert it into the Halloween?:

```
let Year = new Date().getFullYear()
    console.log(Year)
```

Comment: `new Date(Year, 9, 31)`…

Comment: Have you tried this `Halloween.setYear('2020')` ?

Comment: `let halloween = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 9, 31)`

Answer (score 0):

K fixed it.

```
var now = new Date();

var Monthrn = (now.getMonth());

var Dayrn = now.getDate();

if(Monthrn == 10 && Dayrn == 31){
    console.log("Happy Halloween");
    
}

if(Monthrn == 12 && Dayrn == 25){
    console.log("Merry Christmas");
    
}
```